# How do I write an application for Mac OSX from scratch?

Tags: macos

Can anyone guide me how to write a Mac application right from scratch, I'm new to Mac concepts, though I have worked on iPad, iPhone applications. Even a tutorial would work...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

1, Join [Apple's developer program](http://developer.apple.com/devcenter/mac/index.action) (free)
2. [Download Xcode](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/) (free) and learn Objective-C or [Swift](https://developer.apple.com/swift/)  (Swift is easier to learn than Objective-C)
3. Have a great idea!
4. Code!

Answer (score 2):

Although a bit old, I think [cocoadevcentral](http://cocoadevcentral.com/) is an ok place to start.

Answer (score 2):

[Cocoa Programming for Mac OS X](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321503619) by Hillegass is a good book for learning about Mac GUI programming (Objective C and Cocoa).